# "How to consolidate Values present in Unique Rownames" and add a row containing their Sum

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, data-analysis, data-processing

I want to append  2 Rows (Yes/No) for Each Unique Session name.

> Eg:
>   Take 1st Session
>   I want to Add 2 Rows Yes and No which comprises of values as stated below
>   Yes -> "On Duty + Attended + Online Prescence" => 25+30+40 = 95 
>   No -> "Did Not Attend => 10.

Is there any way to do it in Python.

My input is given below

`[image: First Level]

---------------------------------------

My Final output Should Look like this[image: Final Level]

Comment: 1. Do not post data as images, give the data in such a format that they can be used in code examples. 2. What does this question have to do with R?

Comment: You can spread your data using tidyr::spread, group by name and then generate two columns yes and no and later on gather again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea via `dplyr` with only fault that the `Yes` and `No` appear at the top of each group,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(Name, grp = cumsum(Status == 'Did not attend')) %>% 
 summarise(count = sum(count)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-grp) %>% 
 mutate(Status = rep(c('Yes', 'No'), length(unique(Name)))) %>% 
 bind_rows(df) %>% 
 arrange(Name)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 17 x 3
>     Name count Status         
>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          
>  1     1    95 Yes            
>  2     1    10 No             
>  3     1    25 On Duty        
>  4     1    30 Attended       
>  5     1    40 Online Presence
>  6     1    10 Did not attend 
>  7     2   110 Yes            
>  8     2    20 No             
>  9     2    20 On Duty        
> 10     2    50 Attended       
> 11     2    40 Online Presence
> 12     2    20 Did not attend 
> 13     3    26 Yes            
> 14     3    11 No             
> 15     3    11 On Duty        
> 16     3    15 Attended       
> 17     3    11 Did not attend
> ```

**DATA:**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Name = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Status = c("On Duty", 
"Attended", "Online Presence", "Did not attend", "On Duty", "Attended", 
"Online Presence", "Did not attend", "On Duty", "Attended", "Did not attend"
), count = c(25, 30, 40, 10, 20, 50, 40, 20, 11, 15, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: If I have Multiple Statuses other than "Attended", "Online Presence", "Did not attend", "On Duty", it may be a problem. Is there any way to Specify a variable for Summing up particular Columns!. Thanks, By the way

Comment: It will only be a problem If the 'Did not attend' (i.e. the `No`) is not last in every group. If the last entry for every session is `Did not attend` and it's the only 'No' then It should be ok. Otherwise It might be better to create a mapping vector (or data frame) with the yes - Status and the No-Status